# OpenGL Offscreen Rendering Returning Clear Color

Tags: c++, opengl

I have a simple function which is supposed to take in an existing texture present in OpenGL and resize/downsize it to a given width and height and return the ID of the new texture id.

It works perfectly fine the first time and the code can be run multiple times (in a loop) upon the same source texture and even the resultant texture. However once a frame has passed the code no longer works. The result once the function is broken is a texture with the correct width and height input however it does not use the input texture at all and the output pixels are that of the clear color used `glClearColor(0, 1, 1, 1);`. Using legacy OpenGL code to display a colored quad also works once and then stops working leading me to suggest that the problem is not with the input texture but the geometry is not being drawn in the FBO.

```
GLuint Texture::Downsample(int width, int height, GLuint source)
{
    // Use the largest values
    width = Max(16, width);
    height = Max(16, height);

    // Create a frame buffer object
    GLuint fbo, rbo, target_texture;
    glGenFramebuffers(1, &fbo);
    glBindFramebuffer(GL_FRAMEBUFFER, fbo);
    glGenTextures(1, &target_texture); // Create the target texture

    GLenum status;

    // : Target Texture :
    glBindTexture(GL_TEXTURE_2D, target_texture); // Bind the texture position unit to be used as a buffer
    glTexParameteri(GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL_TEXTURE_MAG_FILTER, GL_NEAREST);
    glTexParameteri(GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL_TEXTURE_MIN_FILTER, GL_NEAREST);
    glTexParameterf(GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL_TEXTURE_WRAP_S, GL_CLAMP_TO_EDGE);
    glTexParameterf(GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL_TEXTURE_WRAP_T, GL_CLAMP_TO_EDGE);
    glTexImage2D(GL_TEXTURE_2D, 0, GL_RGB, width, height, 0, GL_RGBA, GL_UNSIGNED_SHORT, NULL);
    glFramebufferTexture2D(GL_FRAMEBUFFER, GL_COLOR_ATTACHMENT0, GL_TEXTURE_2D, target_texture, 0); // Setup the Framebuffer
    status = glCheckFramebufferStatus(GL_FRAMEBUFFER);
    if (status != GL_FRAMEBUFFER_COMPLETE) throw;

    glGenRenderbuffers(1, &rbo);
    glBindRenderbuffer(GL_RENDERBUFFER, rbo);
    glRenderbufferStorage(GL_RENDERBUFFER, GL_DEPTH_COMPONENT, width, height);
    glFramebufferRenderbuffer(GL_FRAMEBUFFER, GL_DEPTH_ATTACHMENT, GL_RENDERBUFFER, rbo);
    status = glCheckFramebufferStatus(GL_FRAMEBUFFER);
    if (status != GL_FRAMEBUFFER_COMPLETE) throw;

    glBindFramebuffer(GL_FRAMEBUFFER, 0);
    glBindRenderbuffer(GL_RENDERBUFFER, 0);
    glBindTexture(GL_TEXTURE_2D, 0);

    // Use the FBO to draw to the color attachment
    glBindFramebuffer(GL_DRAW_FRAMEBUFFER, fbo);
    glDrawBuffer(GL_COLOR_ATTACHMENT0);

    glPushAttrib(GL_VIEWPORT_BIT | GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT);
    glViewport(0, 0, width, height);
    glClearColor(0, 1, 1, 1);
    glClear(GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT | GL_DEPTH_BUFFER_BIT);
    glDisable(GL_DEPTH_TEST);

    // : Draw the original texture
    glMatrixMode(GL_PROJECTION);
    glLoadIdentity();
    glMatrixMode(GL_MODELVIEW);
    glLoadIdentity();

    //this->Bind(GL_TEXTURE0);
    glEnable(GL_TEXTURE_2D);
    glActiveTexture(GL_TEXTURE0);
    glBindTexture(GL_TEXTURE_2D, source);
    glTexParameteri(GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL_TEXTURE_WRAP_S, GL_REPEAT);
    glTexParameteri(GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL_TEXTURE_WRAP_T, GL_REPEAT);
    glTexParameteri(GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL_TEXTURE_MIN_FILTER, GL_LINEAR);
    glTexParameteri(GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL_TEXTURE_MAG_FILTER, GL_LINEAR);

    glDisable(GL_DEPTH_TEST);                                                       // Disable Depth Testing
    glDisable(GL_CULL_FACE);

    // Geometry Data
    const float uvdata[] = { 0.0f, 0.0f, 1.0f, 0.0f, 1.0f, 1.0f, 0.0f, 1.0f };
    const float geometrydata[] = { -1.0f, -1.0f, 0.0f, 1.0f, -1.0f, 0.0f, 1.0f, 1.0f, 0.0f, -1.0f, 1.0f, 0.0f };
    const unsigned char indices[] = { 0, 1, 2, 2, 3, 0 };

    glEnableClientState(GL_VERTEX_ARRAY);                               // Enable Client Vertex Arrays
    glEnableClientState(GL_TEXTURE_COORD_ARRAY);                // Enable Client Texture Coordinate Arrays

    glVertexPointer(3, GL_FLOAT, 0, &geometrydata[0]);      // Pass the geometry data into the Vertex Array
    glTexCoordPointer(2, GL_FLOAT, 0, &uvdata[0]);              // Pass the UV data into the Texture Coordinate Array

    // Draw the geometry using the indices
    glDrawElements(GL_TRIANGLES, 6, GL_UNSIGNED_BYTE, indices);

    glDisableClientState(GL_TEXTURE_COORD_ARRAY);               // Disable Client Texture Coordinate Arrays
    glDisableClientState(GL_VERTEX_ARRAY);                              // Disable Client Vertex Arrays

    glPopAttrib();

    glDeleteTextures(1, &source); // Delete the old texture

    glDrawBuffer(GL_NONE);
    glBindFramebuffer(GL_FRAMEBUFFER, 0);
    glBindRenderbuffer(GL_RENDERBUFFER, 0);
    glBindTexture(GL_TEXTURE_2D, 0);
    glDeleteFramebuffers(1, &fbo);
    glDeleteRenderbuffers(1, &rbo);

    glActiveTexture(GL_TEXTURE0);
    glBindTexture(GL_TEXTURE_2D, target_texture);
    int w, h;
    int miplevel = 0;
    glGetTexLevelParameteriv(GL_TEXTURE_2D, miplevel, GL_TEXTURE_WIDTH, &w);
    glGetTexLevelParameteriv(GL_TEXTURE_2D, miplevel, GL_TEXTURE_HEIGHT, &h);

    return target_texture;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Found the answer (as per usual 10 minutes after I made the question). I am running a multi-context implementation of OpenGL. Thus the input texture ID was being used immediately after the function had returned, however the GPU had not finished processing.

Just adding a `glFinish()` before the return and creating a mutex lock scenario worked a charm. Then when the texture is accessed a try-lock on the mutex is made to determine if its in use or not.

eg.

    `Mutex.Instance.lock();
    TextureID_Internal = Downsample(128,128, TextureID_Internal);
    Mutex.Instance.unlock();`